# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: java, android

I tried on my phone it works fine with my samsung A5 2017, but when I try to run applications in samsung s10 + shows :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING
>   at line 1 column 1 path $

```
@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String massage) {

     Type type = new TypeToken < ArrayList < HashMap < String, String >>> () {}.getType();

     Gson gson = new Gson();
     String temp = massage.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
     String temp2 = temp.replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement("$"), "");
     String newMassage = temp2.substring(1, temp2.length() - 1);

     ArrayList < HashMap < String, String >> arr = gson.fromJson(newMassage, type);



     for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
         if (!Objects.equals(arr.get(i).get("region"), city)) {
             arr.get(i).clear();
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: print your response

Comment: i mean the result content return from server

Answer (score 0):

In Json,

[ ... ] mean Array

{ ... }  mean object

The particularity of json data, first remove the "$", then need to remove the "\".

```
String temp = massage.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
String temp2= temp .replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement("$"), "");
```

The "temp2" is the json string data.The last step is to remove the first and last quotation marks.

```
String newMassage = temp2.substring(1, temp2.length()-1);
```

and

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arr = gson.fromJson(newMassage, type);
```

Comment: I tried on my phone it works fine with my samsung A5 2017, but when I try to run applications in samsung s10 + shows it java.lang . IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $